PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null) await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
While run release app.
pick image from device and during store that path during throw this error.

PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Here code.
Future<String> _saveToInternalStorage(XFile file) async {
    String newPath = '';
    try {
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      newPath = '${directory.path}/${file.name}';
      await file.saveTo(newPath);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error accessing documents directory: $e");
    }
    return newPath;
  }

get permission
Future<void> pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    if (/*await _requestPermission(Permission.camera) &&*/ await _requestPermission(Permission.photos) && await _requestPermission(Permission.mediaLibrary)) {
      final XFile? pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: source);

      if (pickedFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
          if (imageList[i].path.isEmpty) {
            String path = await _saveToInternalStorage(pickedFile);
            imageList[i] = XFile(path);
            break;
          }
        }
        refresh();
      }
    } else {
      print('Permissions not granted');
    }
  }

